# How to set google sitelinks search box for search engine result page

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a website `www.mysite.com`
and a google custom search engine in `www.mysite.com/google-search-engine/`

i want to add google sitelinks search box to my website search engine resault page.

i have this examples:

Put the schema.org markup on my homepage.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>


<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.example.com/"/>
  <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}"/>
    <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term_string" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

how to do this in magento home page?

[google blog guide](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/slsb-overview?utm_source=wmc-blog&utm_medium=direct-referral&utm_campaign=sitelinks-searchbox)

> a. **"url"**—This property specifies the URL of your website. It must match
>   the canonical URL of your domain's homepage.
>
> b.**potentialAction:target**—This property specifies a search URL
>   pattern for sending queries to your site's search engine. Key points
>   about the URL pattern:
>   -It must include a string enclosed in curly braces that is a placeholder for the user's search query (e.g., {search_term_string}).
>   The string inside the curly braces must also appear in the name
>   attribute of the query-input property.
>   -It must point to the same domain on which the markup is found.
>   -An actual query string instead of the placeholder string must produce a valid search results page on your site.
>
> c.**query-input**—the value for the name attribute of query-input must
>   match the string enclosed inside curly braces in the target property
>   of potentialAction.

this is an image for "sitelinks search box in search engine resault page":
[image]

Comment: you can simply add these code block in your `cms` page (choose home page). you need to change `target` url.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri i should change target url to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this functionality easily with use of static block and little local.xml change

just create first static block from cms menu in admin with id `google_sitelinks_searchbox_js`

and add this code to your block

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "WebSite",
            "url": "http://www.youtdomain.com/",
            "potentialAction": {
                "@type": "SearchAction",
                "target": "http://www.youtdomain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={search_term}&order=relevance&dir=desc",
                "query-input": "required name=search_term"
                }
        }
</script>
```

after that just add below xml code to your `local.xml`

```
<cms_index_index>    
     <reference name="before_body_end">
     <block type="cms/block" name="google_sitelinks_searchbox">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>google_sitelinks_searchbox_js</block_id></action>
        </block>  
    </reference>    
</cms_index_index>
```

and you then clear `cache` and see this js code on home page source.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: unfortunatly this has disabled my sitemap from google search engine resault page!

Comment: it's working for me. Don't when you wrong..

Comment: Do i need to rebuild my sitemap after doing this solution ?

Comment: and where should i put this code in my local.xml exactly?

Comment: under `<cms_index_index> ` tag which is already mention in my answer.i would be happy if you vote up so atleast someone can trust and use this answer

Comment: i have putted my local.xml in answers. can you please edit my answer and put the code in write place please?
i will thankful if you do this favor for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have it in search results page, then you will need to add new block in your xml.

Go to your `theme/layout/catalogsearch.xml` and find `<reference name="content">`
add following code after that line-

```
<block type="core/template" name="google-search" template="page/google.phtml"/>
```

Now create a file called `google.phtml` in your `template/page` folder. And paste your google code in that page.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "http://localhost/magento/",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "http://localhost/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>


<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://localhost/magento/"/>
  <form itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SearchAction">
    <meta itemprop="target" content="http://localhost/magento/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q={search_term_string}"/>
    <input itemprop="query-input" type="text" name="search_term_string" required/>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

You will need to change `http://localhost/magento/` to your domain name. After this clear your cache, and it should appear in your search result page.

I haven't tested this on live site, should work though.

> **UPDATE 1**

Add following code in to your `cms > home page > content` area:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "http://www.yoursite.com/",
   "potentialAction": {
     "@type": "SearchAction",
     "target": "http://www.yoursite.com/catalogsearch/result/?q={search_term_string}",
     "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't want it to be in magento search result page. i want it to be in home page. can you read my question again pleas? i updated it.

Comment: Try this then: https://cse.google.com/cse/manage/all